# Workbench not working

Tags: soql, workbench

When i tried quering the salesforce object with linked logged in environment, I'm facing error message saying Service was temporarily interrupted or is unavailable. Please try again in a moment."

[image]"

Answer (score 6):

I've seen a report of a major [AWS outage today in the East coast server farm](https://www.theverge.com/2020/11/25/21719396/amazon-web-services-aws-outage-down-internet). Along with reports that Heroku/Heroku Connect is also affected. It is unclear if they are related or not.

A Heroku issue would well affect the hosted version of workbench that Salesforce provides.

The [Heroku Status page](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2127) is showing an issue being investigated.
[image]

Comment: Note. I was able to connect to https://workbench.developerforce.com/ just now and run a SOQL query without issue.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Given this answer, I've removed mine. A temporary outage would likely be the explanation for the service disruption.